# Installing iOS app to non tester device through Diawi

Tags: ios, build

Is it possible to install the app through a 3rd party service like diawi.com on a device that is not registered as a tester device on my profile on developer apple?

I already have a developer account but I want to be able to test the application on my friends phones before submitting it on apple store and getting all of their uuid is pretty difficult and currently I can't get access to those devices in order to install it directly.

Update Testflight

So I uploaded my build in TestFlight and is in this status:

[uploaded build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH99a.png)

I created a test group, added the build:

[Added build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLCMj.png)

And added a tester:

[Added testers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfbhd.png)

But after adding the tester it dosent send the invite to the app, it just says no build available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Follow the steps below:

1. Upload a build to TestFlight.
2. Create a new External App Tester Group.

[image]

3. Open the newly created group and goto the Build tab. Add Build uploaded in Step 1 here and follow the further steps.

[image]

And Finally submit for the app for beta review, after apple review finished, you can generate a link and share it with your friends.

Comment: @Cristian-Alexandru SANDU let me know if you have any question on the above solution

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am having troubles with TestFlight, check my updates I posted some photos there.

Comment: Never mind, I received some emails from Apple and now I understand what is going on, but this process is so time consuming, a little bit annoying.