# Can I distribute an iOS app over-the-air from an individual account?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, over-the-air

I can distribute an iOS app over-the-air to my own personal phone; however, installing it (using the exact same hyperlink etc.) on any other phone seems to not work.

I am using an individual iOS account; I have a hunch that this is due to the fact that I'm not using an Enterprise account, but I cannot confirm this, and have yet been unable to find evidence of this.

Is that the reason why, or is there some other reason why my app only can install on my personal phone and not others? Thanks.

Comment: You need to include in the provisioning profile  the udid for any phones that you want to distribute to. You should use TestFlight for beta testing prior to releasing through the App Store.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61011677/2781088 ... If it solves your purpose.